# rails, finding a string and truncating a text block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given a text block like

```
yada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yada

On Tue, Nov 16, 2010 at 9:23 PM, Tekkub <tender+xxxxxxx@tenderapp.com> wrote:
```

With Rails3, I'd like to know, given a text block, how to find a string like:

```
On Tue, Nov 16, 2010 at 9:23 PM, Tekkub <tender+xxxxxxx@tenderapp.com> wrote:
```

And then create a new variable with just the text above that matched string.

Thanks

...

Ideas:
1. First need to generate that string give the day, month:

```
On Tue, Nov 16, 2010 at 9:23 PM, Tekkub <tender+xxxxxxx@tenderapp.com> wrote:
```

1. Use that string to then do a FIND? and some how apply a LEFT?

Comment: Does it always start with `On` and end with a colon?

Comment: It should, it's an email reply

Comment: Are you using this line as a delimiter for the body text above it? What if the quote-string (and quoted text) is *above* the actual body text?

Comment: @Eric, ya that's the current idea. But I'm open for a better one. the goal is given an incoming email which is a reply, being able to extract the reply message without all the junk in the email (previous threads, emails), date stamps etc. Just get the reply text, and insert that in the DB as a comment. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you could do this using the `scan()` method from ruby's `String` class and a regex. This method is brittle, because it relies on the fact that `On` will always start the string you are looking for, and a `:` will always end it. But, if you say that "it should," then this will work well. This code sample assumes that `@emailreply` is an instance variable containing the entire body of the email reply as a string, and will return an array of 1 containing the extracts. `scan()` returns an array of all the regex matches from the string.

```
 def extract_info
    extracts = @emailreply.scan(/On.*?:/)
    extracts
 end
```

Comment: Hmmm thanks Alex, but I'd rather build the full string to be safe, and then find a match. Is that possible?

Comment: @AnApprentice I believe so. Would you mind explaining more about what you mean by "building the full string" first? Isn't this entire string part of a emailreply?

Comment: @Alex, thanks. Ya so the goal is to make a very positive match on this string "On Tue, Nov 16, 2010 at 9:23 PM, Tekkub <tender+xxxxxxx@tenderapp.com> wrote:" to make sure what I grab and then inject into the database is a comment. Avoiding false positives is very important. so the idea is, since we know the current data (today is Nov 17) I can use that to find: "On, Tue, Nov 16, 2010 at X:XX PM, XXXXXX <useremail@tenderapp.com> wrote:" The idea is I can match to Tue, Nov, 16, 2010, and the user's email address. Does that help?

Comment: The XXXX's represent something I'd want to ignore since it's variable, no specific.. What do you think?

Comment: @AnApprentice Ah! So you are after the user's email address and the date only?

Comment: I'm after what's above. I can use the date and email address to make a positive match since that's at the bottom of the email. I use those fields to make the match and grab the text above and insert it into the DB as a comment.

Comment: Or what about finding a line where "On Nov 17, 2010" exists in the begining of the line, and the line is ended with "wrote:" And then using that location to grab everything before that line only. Possible?

Comment: @AnApprentice Yes. To a certain extent, you can utilize regular expressions to do some pretty powerful matching and data extraction.

Comment: @AnApprentice I will edit my answer when I have some time to reflect these comments. :)